Why I get error "The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a t" with enabled -rectypes flag
I would like to write catamorphism in OCaml for any endofunctor (in terms of types) as a functor (in terms of OCaml):
module type Functor = sig

    type 'a t

    (* ... *)
end

module Make(F : Functor) = struct

    type fix_t = 'a F.t as 'a

    (* ... *)
end

But this code produces an error: "The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a F.t".
I know that there is "-rectypes" flag for OCaml compiler, and following type definition is accepted in place of fix_t: type fix_list = 'a list as 'a.
So I think that an error produced by unknown type t, but it looks strange for me, that type checker distinguish between known and unknown types here.

Perhaps this is because t might get defined as type 'a t = 'a in which case fix_t would not be a proper recursive but a vacuous type.

Even with -rectypes, recursive types must be contractive: all recursive variables must occur as arguments of builtin or datatype type constructors. Without this constraint, equations of the form
type 'a id = 'a
type t = 'a id as 'a

could be accepted and would allow multiple incomparable solutions (for instance t=int or t=float).
Thus, it is simpler to avoid -rectypes, and use an explicit constructor for guarding recursion:
type fix = Fix of fix t [@@unboxed]


Thank you! Could you add some reference links to learn more about compiler behaviour?
